# CardView not shown on RecyclerView (In Fragment)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I want to make CardViews visible on a RecyclerView inside a Fragment, but all I get is a infinite loading sign and no cardviews are being showed. I'm very new to Android Programming so please be kind..

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentPage fragment = new FragmentPage();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.placeholder, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


    ViewPager viewpager = findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

    SwipeAdapter adapter = new SwipeAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewpager.setPageTransformer(true, new DepthPageTransformer());

    viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);


    }
}
```

This is my Adapter class(I followed a Tutorial)

```
public class ListAdapterIT extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 0;
}

private class ListViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private ImageView mImageView;

    public ListViewHolder (View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image2);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

    }


    public void BindViewHolder(int position) {
        mImageView.setImageResource(OurData.picturePath[position]);

    }


    public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    }


}
```

This is my Fragment I also think the Problem is in that class

```
public class FragmentPage extends Fragment {




@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_fragment, container, false);

    ArrayList<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();
    items.add(R.layout.example_item);


    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.listRecyclerView);

    ListAdapterIT listAdapter = new ListAdapterIT() {};
    recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);



    return view;
    }

}
```

Comment: It looks like you never pass any data to the adapter. Even if you did, your adapter returns zero from getItemCount(). So the "system" thinks there is nothing to show. I don't know where the loading sign comes from but maybe your first step should be to learn how to set up a RecyclerView.Adapter properly. See for example this [guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: Thank you for the quick, I've been stuck on this step for a while now and it really starts to get intimidating. I will definetly try the guide and share my progress with you. Wish me luck